# What has been deprecated or removed in OS X 10.9, Mavericks?

Tags: software-update, macos

For the last couple of releases of OS X, there have been some parts of the OS and the utilities that have been simplified or removed compared to the previous release. Especially as seem from a power users point-of-view.

Two examples from past releases are the scaled down AirPort Utility (version 6.0) and the limitations in "Sharing" System Preference panel that used to be able to manage FTP servers - both changes have been rather annoying in my book!

So, before I "upgrade" to Mavericks, I would like to know if there are anything specific that will be "downgraded" in the same process.

Comment: Not to mention one-click web sharing (well, you did kinda mention it..!)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [Apple support communities](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23444401#23444401), it apparently won't be possible to synchronize calendars and contacts between the Mac and an iPhone via USB connection or local WLAN anymore. The only remaining directly supported option would be via cloud synchronization (e.g., iCloud).